# How to start TortoiseSVN Project Monitor (part of Tortoise SVN)?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do I start "TortoiseSVN Project Monitor" which is part of Tortoise SVN?

It started automatically, but I closed it. Now I can't see a way to start it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call the universal TortoiseProc.exe with the command monitor:
On my machine this is the call:

`"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:monitor`

Comment: This command opens Project Monitor. He appears to be talking about an entirely [different tool](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/).

Comment: are you sure? he tagged only tortoisesvn, so I assumed it is the project monitor. @Danijel: please clarify, I will remove my answer if you related to the svnnnotifier from tigris as Álvaro suggests

Comment: I ment TortoiseSVN Project Monitor, sorry. I edited the question. Thanks for the answer, it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can click on the start menu icon:

[image: Start Menu Icons]]

... or, if you use Windows 7 or later, just trigger the "Start" button and start typing:

[image: Start typing...]

Comment: Not sure what your exact concern is. Being able to launch any app just by typing 2 or 3 letters of its name is awesome. And it never hurts to know apps by name (rather than just by icon) because icons tend to change along releases.

Comment: I miss focus. In previous Win versions I would select Tortoise SVN, and then easily see all shortcuts that belong to it. In Win 8 I need to type the name, and then it shows me a buch of names which I don't even know where they belong. Or are they even shortcuts, or just some search terms suggested!? Totaly confusing.

Comment: You should had migrated to Windows 10 while it was free. They fixed many of the Start Menu issues and now it's great. It's the only new feature that doesn't suck.